# rails add css class if the page has a 404 status

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there a way in Rails to add a class to a html tag if the current page rendered a 404 error.

On a controller of mine, if a user visits the wrong website it renders a file in the public error with a 404 error like this

```
else
  render file: 'public/error', status: 404, formats: [:html]
end
```

I want to add a class to my footer, `hidden`, to hide the footer if this page is rendered. I've tried this with no luck (but it was more of a guess)

```
<%= "hidden" if current_page?(status: 404) %>
```

Any suggestions??

Comment: You have `400` there, not `404`. If you change that, does your code work?

Comment: Haha good eye, but still no luck. I figured out a way around it. I just made a stylesheet on that file and hid the footer from the stylesheet. :) Thanks for taking a look at it though! I am still curious about the answer though, so I'll leave it up in case someone knows the answer other than the side trick I did

Comment: In Rails 3, you can do `<%= "hidden" if controller.status == 404 %>` but I'm too lazy to test that in 4 so I'm writing a comment, not an answer :)

Comment: lol thanks i love it @mechanicalfish. That being said it didn't work :) Thanks anyway for taking a look at it

Answer (score 1):

You could make it more generic and set an `@variable` to tell the footer to hide. So if later on you want a 500 page without footer you can use the same trick.

controller

```
else
  @hide_footer = true
  render file: 'public/error', status: 404, formats: [:html]
end
```

view

```
<%= "hidden" if @hide_footer %>
```

And you don't need to change anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You could just render a separate layout for your error files

```
else
    render :template => "shared/404", :layout => 'errorlayout', :status => 404
end
```

You might want to have a look at these questions and answers as well:

[Dynamic error pages in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331008/dynamic-error-pages-in-rails-3)

[how to remove header and footer from some of the pages in ruby on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11311090/how-to-remove-header-and-footer-from-some-of-the-pages-in-ruby-on-rails)

[How to hide footer layout on a particular page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131073/how-to-hide-footer-layout-on-a-particular-page) - This is basically Ismael Abreu suggestion and is probably the easiest.